# Slack bot creation using Nodejs in Salesforce

Tags: node.js

I was trying to create a slack bot when trying to verify server I am getting the following error:

```
     C:\Users\Jagadeep\Desktop\first-slack-app\node_modules\.bin\slack-verify:2
  basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
      ^^^^^^^
     SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Can anyone help me with this please.

Answer (score 0):

You can try code below. That solved my problem.
`node node_modules/@slack/events-api/dist/verify.js --secret <secret> --path=/@slack/events-api --port=3000`